# Ruby on Rails sitemap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a ROR apps that selling items such as chair, table etc. I am using `gem  sitemap_generator` to generate the sitemap. Here is the code of my sitemap:

```
# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.example.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add '/products', :priority => 0.7, :changefreq => 'daily'
end
```

When I run the command `rake sitemap:refresh` a `sitemap.xml.gz` is created in public folder.
My `robots.txt` as follow:

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
#
# To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
# User-agent: *
# Disallow: /
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

Would this mean, all my products at `www.example.com/products` will be available for google to index?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just download your sitemap from `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml.gz` and you will see the same URLs as Google will see when it downloads the file...

Comment: @spickermann thanks. This is what I see `<url><loc>http://www.example.com</loc><lastmod>2016-02-03T20:56:42+08:00</lastmod><changefreq>always</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url><url><loc>http://www.example.com/products</loc><lastmod>2016-02-03T20:56:42+08:00</lastmod><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority></url></urlset>`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're better off using the url helpers rather than explicit paths. This way if the paths ever change due to modifications to your `routes.rb` file, you wont need to worry about your sitemap being wrong:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add products_url, priority: 0.7, changefreq: 'daily'
end
```

Next, the products url you've added above will only add `/products` to your sitemap. You might want to add each individual product, depending on the frequency of them changing:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add products_path, priority: 0.7, changefreq: 'daily'

  Product.all.each do |product|
    add product_path(product), priority: 0.7, changefreq: 'daily'
  end
end
```

Obviously, you will need to trigger a sitemap refresh each time you add/remove a product.

Comment: thanks jon. So now google will go through each of the products? Am I right? So for each the product, I need to use itemprop for schema right?

Comment: You're talking about `Microdata`, which is markup in your page to tell the search engine what content is what on a page. I don't see how this is applicable to your sitemap.